# What's wrong with Groovy multi-line String?

Tags: string, groovy, multiline

Groovy scripts raises an error:

```
def a = "test"
  + "test"
  + "test"
```

Error:

```
No signature of method: java.lang.String.positive() is 
applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

While this script works fine:

```
def a = new String(
  "test"
  + "test"
  + "test"
)
```

Why?

Comment: In case it helps somebody else, you can get the same error with code like `def a = b + + "/" + c`. In this case the two + symbols are obviously the problem.

Comment: You can see the groovy multiline strings documentation: https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-strings

Answer (score 302, accepted):

As groovy doesn't have EOL marker (such as `;`) it gets confused if you put the operator on the following line

This would work instead:

```
def a = "test" +
  "test" +
  "test"
```

as the Groovy parser knows to expect something on the following line

Groovy sees your original `def` as three separate statements.  The first assigns `test` to `a`, the second two try to make `"test"` positive (and this is where it fails)

With the `new String` constructor method, the Groovy parser is still in the constructor (as the brace hasn't yet closed), so it can logically join the three lines together into a single statement

For true multi-line Strings, you can also use the triple quote:

```
def a = """test
test
test"""
```

Will create a String with test on three lines

Also, you can make it neater by:

```
def a = """test
          |test
          |test""".stripMargin()
```

the [`stripMargin` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#stripMargin%28%29) will trim the left (up to and including the `|` char) from each line

Comment: Or simply use [stripIndent()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#stripIndent%28%29) instead of `stripMargin()`.

Comment: Yeah, and omit the `|` chars on the extra lines

Comment: In my case i cannot use " " " because i have something like a JSON i mean with many double quotes inside so i use single quotes to avoid the need of escape all those double quotes and make the code cleaner. But i also want to split the string in seveal files ... is there a different approach?

Comment: You can use double quotes inside `"""` strings

Comment: @sschuberth does the stripIndent() actually work here, since the documentation states: "The line with the least number of leading spaces determines the number to remove." In this case that would be the first line with zero leading spaces.

Comment: Right, I've edited the answer to show how you would need to slightly reformat the code to make `stripIndent()` work.

Comment: @sschuberth why? Post it as a separate answer

Comment: Because a) I had already posted it as a comment, and b) it's not much different from this answer.

Comment: Anyway, as I just saw you undid my edit, I've posted it as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45305802/1127485) now.

Comment: Why was the `stripIndent()` edit rolled back? It made this answer stronger, IMO.

Answer (score 48):

Similar to `stripMargin()`, you could also use [stripIndent()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#stripIndent(java.lang.CharSequence)) like

```
def a = """\
        test
        test
        test""".stripIndent()
```

Because of

> The line with the least number of leading spaces determines the number to remove.

you need to also indent the first "test" and not put it directly after the inital `"""` (the `\` ensures the multi-line string does not start with a newline).

Comment: what's the \ for?

Comment: I've improved my last sentence to better explain it.

Answer (score 27):

You can tell Groovy that the statement should evaluate past the line ending by adding a pair of parentheses `( ... )`

```
def a = ("test"
  + "test"
  + "test")
```

A second option is to use a backslash, `\`, at the end of each line:

```
def a = "test" \
  + "test" \
  + "test"
```

FWIW, this is identical to how Python multi-line statements work.

Comment: The second one is also how VBA multiline statements work :D (Only with underscores instead of backslashes, because VBA.)

Comment: Second option failed for me in a Jenkinsfile. First option worked.

Comment: Nitpick: Python multi-line string doesn't require the concatenation operator when using parens, so it's not exactly the same.