# Groovy / Postgres "No signature of method: java.lang.String.positive()"

Tags: groovy

Trying to write some basic PostgreSQL code using JDBC to eventually integrate into an application written in Groovy. I have written this Groovy code to connect to the DB and then execute statements; but, I'm getting an error that I have tried to find a solution to, and could not. Here is the relevant part of the Groovy code, along with a comment as to where the error appears to be happening:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)

println "Sql Instance: " + sql

sql.execute(
        " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;"
        + "CREATE TABLE test ("
            + "id SERIAL,"
            + "word TEXT,"
            + "number INTEGER,"
            + "decimal NUMERIC,"
            + "datetime TIMESTAMP"
            + ");"
 )

def params = ['Hello, World!', 42, 3.14159, null]

sql.execute("INSERT INTO test (word, number, decimal, datetime)"
            + "VALUES (?,?,?,?);", params)

sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM test;") { row ->
    println "The row Id is: ${row.id}"
        // HERE??
        + "The word is: ${row.word}"
        + "The number is: ${row.number}"
        + "The decimal is: ${row.decimal}"
        + "The date-time is: ${row.datetime}"
}
sql.close()
```

The console log says:

> ```
>     Sql Instance: groovy.sql.Sql@5aa9e4eb
>     The row Id is: 1
>     Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.positive() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>     Possible solutions: notify(), tokenize(), size(), size()
>     groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.positive() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>     Possible solutions: notify(), tokenize(), size(), size()
>         at DatabaseTest$_run_closure1.doCall(DatabaseTest.groovy:34)
>         at DatabaseTest.run(DatabaseTest.groovy:31)
>         at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>
>     Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

don't use the dreaded string-concatenation! In Groovy there's a nice replacement:

```
println """The row Id is: ${row.id}
    The word is: ${row.word}
    The number is: ${row.number}
    The decimal is: ${row.decimal}
    The date-time is: ${row.datetime}"""
```

Comment: WOW, that solved the problem instantly. I'm guessing that can be done for all Sql strings? (or most anyways)

Comment: @Phrancis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079797/whats-wrong-with-groovy-multi-line-string/5079914#5079914

Answer (score 41):

The other answer gave you the solution I also would recommend, but it can be good to still know the *reason* for **why** this is happening.

Groovy uses *operator overloading* quite excessively. This means that if you were to write your own class, you can overload the `+` operator to do many things.

However, there is a difference between using `+` at the end of a line and at the beginning of a line.

At the end of a line, `+` is treated as the *binary operator* `append` (`a + b`), but at the start of a line, it is treated as the *unary operator* `positive` (`+6` is treated as "positive six").

If you were to write this, it would work better:

```
println "The row Id is: ${row.id}" +
    "The word is: ${row.word}" +
    "The number is: ${row.number}" +
    "The decimal is: ${row.decimal}" +
    "The date-time is: ${row.datetime}"
```

If you would do this, however, you would get the output on one line, that's because you haven't added new line characters, `\n`

```
println "The row Id is: ${row.id}\n" +
    "The word is: ${row.word}\n" +
    "The number is: ${row.number}\n" +
    "The decimal is: ${row.decimal}\n" +
    "The date-time is: ${row.datetime}"
```

And now things are starting to look uglier, which is why Groovy's multi-line String functionality can come in handy, as shown in the other answer.