# Checking if GroovyRowResult field is empty string

Tags: sql, groovy

I am using `sql.firstRow` to check if a row exists in the postgres database based on some criteria.

```
def cur = sql.firstRow(r, '''
                                SELECT "some_thing"
                                FROM "my_table"
                                WHERE "customer_name" = :customer_name
                                AND "sad_date" = :sad_date
                                AND "forgiver" = :forgiver
                            ''')
```

I find that this works:

```
if (cur){
      log.debug("Found Some thing " + cur["some_thing"])
      log.debug("Cur: " + cur.keySet())
}
```

however this lets in any rows that don't have some_field inside it.

**ISSUE**

To avoid this, when we try and check for the existance of a non empty value for `some_field` on the result row like this:

```
if (cur && "${cur.some_thing}" ){
  log.debug("Found Some thing " + cur["some_thing"])
}
```

**ERROR**

I get an *error* suggesting that:

```
No signature of `String.positive` for argument types for the given type.
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044673/groovy-postgres-no-signature-of-method-java-lang-string-positive?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and changed from `cur.some_thing` and `cur['some_thing']` to "${cur.some_thing}" but the error does not go away

I have also tried [this post](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult) and tried to use `cur.getProperty("some_thing")` and it still throws the same error.

Comment: `rows that don't have some_field inside it.` how can that be for a sql DB?

Comment: rows that don't have a non empty value for `some_field`. I understand that Groovy empty string is falsy

Comment: meaning that the value is `null` or empty? or rather the query did not bring any results?

Comment: meaning that the value for cur.some_field is either null or empty string whichever is possible

Comment: Is your error coming from the log statement? Do you just need to repeat the method of accessing the value as per the if statement?

Comment: @vamsiampolu, please provide a full stacktrace and the the part of your code with exact line where the error occurred.

Comment: @MikeW the answer is yes, it is most possibly coming either from a condition statement or a log statement. Removing the cur.some_field variant from the condition no longer shows the issue.