# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: error?

Tags: groovy, jira

I am getting error for the below code

```
def sqlQueryREC="""select jiraissue.id
     from jiraissue WITH (NOLOCK)
     inner join project WITH (NOLOCK)
     on jiraissue.project = project.id
     inner join issuestatus ji WITH (NOLOCK)
     on jiraissue.issuestatus=ji.id
     where project.pkey = 'SWDEV'
     and jiraissue.issuetype in (select id from issuetype where pname in('Defect')""";
```

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.positive() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: notify(), size(), size(), tokenize()

Comment: The error is not that line, it's some other line in your code

Comment: Sounds like you're doing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079797/whats-wrong-with-groovy-multi-line-string/5079914#5079914 somewhere

Comment: you are using `positive()` method on a `String` type var.