# Possible to run multiline shell command/string in groovy/gradle?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy

In gradle 7 I have created this method:

```
def shellCmd(String cmd) {
  exec {
    executable "sh"
    args "-c", cmd
  }
}
```

And this "pure" groovy version:

```
def shellCmd2(String cmd) {
  def process = cmd.execute()
  def output = new StringWriter(), error = new StringWriter()
  process.waitForProcessOutput(output, error)
}
```

Which I call from another method e.g.:

```
def myMethod() {
  shellCmd('ls -la')
}
```

I am now experimenting with getting it to work with multi-line (jenkins like) shell commands:

```
def myMethod() {
  
  def cmd = """
   for i in \$(ls -la); do
     if [[ \$i == 'settings.gradle' ]]; then
       echo "Found $i"
     fi
   done
  """

  shellCmd(cmd)

}
```

but it fails with:

```
  script '/home/user/samples/build.gradle': 47: Unexpected input: 'i' @ line 47, column 5.
     for i in $(ls -la); do
         ^
  
  1 error
```

Probably I am breaking all the rules here but any input?

Also tried most of the suggestions here:

[What's wrong with Groovy multi-line String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079797/whats-wrong-with-groovy-multi-line-string)

but no luck so far.

Also based on the suggestion below I have tried to use `shellCmd2` method (I am leaning towards using a plain groovy method for this to make it easier to debug outside of gradle) with:

```
def myMethod() {

  def cmd = """
  for i in \$(ls -la); do
    if [ \$i = 'settings.gradle' ]; then
      echo "Found \$i"
    fi
  done
  """
  
  shellCmd2(cmd)
}
```

But that gives:

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "for": error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "for": error=2, No such file or directory
```

So seems the `for` keyword is now causing an issue.

Comment: not sure it's possible to put multiline string as a command line. i believe jenkins is creating a temp.sh file and executes it.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your multiline string. I had to change three things to make your code work:

1. Use [single brackets](https://steinbaugh.com/posts/posix.html#conditional-expressions) `[` and `]`
2. Use [single equal sign](https://steinbaugh.com/posts/posix.html#variable-comparisons) (`=`)
3. Escape the missing `$i` variable which was being interpreted as a Groovy variable.

You are using sh so you should only use [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compatible features.

Code:

```
def shellCmd(String cmd) {
  exec {
    executable "sh" // or use another shell like bash or zsh (less portable)
    args "-c", cmd
  }
}

def myMethod() {
    def cmd = """
        for i in \$(ls -la); do
            if [ \$i = 'settings.gradle' ]; then
            echo "Found \$i"
            fi
        done
    """
    shellCmd(cmd)
}
```

You can compare with double brackets with shells like zsh and bash.

Comment: That gives: `Cannot run program "for": error=2, No such file or directory` see my updated example. I assume this is because I now switched from sh to e.g. bash that I am using?